# Find All modes in an array

Tags: java

I have to code in Java to find all max occurring integers in an array. Currently, my code is only returning one mode despite the fact there are multiple integers with the same mode value.Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

```
public static int getMode(int[] values) {
      if(values.length==0)
    return null;
      HashMap<Integer,Integer> freqs = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

      for (int val : values) {
        Integer freq = freqs.get(val);
        freqs.put(val, (freq == null ? 1 : freq+1));
      }

      int mode = 0;
      int maxFreq = 0;

      for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : freqs.entrySet()) {
        int freq = entry.getValue();
        if (freq > maxFreq) {
          maxFreq = freq;
          mode = entry.getKey();
        }
      }

      return mode;
    }
```

Comment: It's returning one mode because you only ever specify to return one mode.  `int` may not be appropriate; perhaps `List<Integer>` as the return type?

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...

// first, you find out what the maximum frequency is 
int maxFreq = 0;
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : freqs.entrySet()) {
    int freq = entry.getValue();
    if (freq > maxFreq) {
        maxFreq = freq;
    }
}

// then, you collect all keys that share the same frequency
List<Integer> modes = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> entry : freqs.entrySet()) {
    int freq = entry.getValue();
    if (freq == maxFreq) {
        modes.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}

return modes;
```